# How to access https protected API from ESP8266?

Tags: javascript, c++, esp8266, vercel

I'll repost all my question because I descovered the problem is the SSL access as pointed by a user here. So I already don't received more 308 message, but my ESP8266 crashes wen I try to access any "https" website.

I'm using this code to try to access:

```
const char* endpoint = "https://hvilela.com:443/api/data/all";

void onClientStateChange(void* arguments,
                         asyncHTTPrequest* aReq,
                         int readyState) {
  Serial.println(readyState);
  switch (readyState) {
    case 0:
      // readyStateUnsent     // Client created, open not yet called
      break;

    case 1:
      // readyStateOpened     // open() has been called, connected
      break;

    case 2:
      // readyStateHdrsRecvd  // send() called, response headers available
      break;

    case 3:
      // readyStateLoading    // receiving, partial data available
      break;

    case 4:
      // readyStateDone       // Request complete, all data available.

#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG
      Serial.println(aReq->responseHTTPcode());
#endif
      if (aReq->responseHTTPcode() != 200) {
#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG
        Serial.println("return");
#endif
        return;
      }
      String response = aReq->responseText();
#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG
      Serial.println(response.c_str());
#endif
      break;
  }
}

void setupClient() {
  
  String URL2 =  endpoint; 

  client2.setTimeout(5);
  client2.setDebug(true);
  client2.onReadyStateChange(onClientStateChange);

  client2.open("GET", URL2.c_str());
  client2.send();

  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("[Client setup end]");
}
```

by accessing this endpoint, I need to receive a 410 Unauthorized message. Works perfectly in web browsers, but not in ESP8266.

Additionally, I'm using PlatformIO VSCode plugin to program.

Comment: 308 is *not* an error. It's an essential part of HTTP. Insomnia, Postman and web browsers are sophisticated enough to automatically process the redirect; the ESP8266 HTTPClient library does not by default. Please edit your question to include the URL you're trying to connect to and the exact Location returned in the redirect - copy and paste them, do not type them in manually. How is your site configured? Is it behind nginx or some other web server?

Comment: @romkey I updated the question with the information I have. About the website server configuration, I don't now the 'behind-the-scenes' that vercel does to get things working.

Comment: In your Arduino code you have `http://`, but your actual URL has `https://`. Trying to access `http://hvilela.com/api/data/all` causes a 308 redirect.

Comment: @gre_gor tried both http and https, get the same "308 Permanent Redirect".

Comment: I think `WiFiClient` needs to be `WiFiSSLClient`

Comment: @AlanBirtles I couldn't find this WiFiSSLClient object, but you made me think about this Secure Access could be the problem. I searched a lot and found some codes, none of them worked (not only for my use, but the example copy/paste itself. Some [using website fingerprint PROGMEM](https://www.dobitaobyte.com.br/como-fazer-https-get-com-esp8266/) , some w/ another way to try to access as using lib WiFi101.h, but after a lot of errors I [discovered](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/WiFi101/issues/234) that this lib is not compatible with ESP8266. I couldn't find a ESP8266 working SSL access.

Comment: [BasicHttpsClient.ino](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/examples/BasicHttpsClient/BasicHttpsClient.ino)?

Comment: It's `WiFiClientSecure`. You need to use it if you're using HTTPS. However, the fact that you got ANY HTTP return code with `WiFiClient` indicates that you used HTTP, not HTTPS. Which is why I don't believe you about the URL you said you used. If you used HTTPS with `WiFiClient` you'd get a failed connection, -1 return. Not a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @gre_gor was the key to discover the real problem.

I got the [BasicHttps](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/examples/BasicHttpsClient/BasicHttpsClient.ino) example and started to work, but not completely worked.

I though about a Vercel server problem, but finally, what explained  the redirects too, was a 'google-domains' related problem I was having.

**hvilela.com** is a name on [google domains](https://domains.google.com/), but inside Vercel this goes to another page (although I don't know why this page was not the Location in 308 advice), and only in this 'inside Vercel' page I could access the API correctly.

Hope this can help who have same problems in future

Answer (score 0):

[here example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Yw2.png)

add `client.setInsecure();` in your code it works for me, i don't get status code 308 anymore

full code:

```js
void fetchAPi() {
  String url = "https://....";
  WiFiClientSecure client;
  HTTPClient http;

  /* Add this */
  client.setInsecure();

  http.begin(client, url.c_str());
  int httpResponseCode = http.GET();

  Serial.print("HTTP Response Code: ");
  Serial.println(httpResponseCode);

  if (httpResponseCode > 0) {
    String response = http.getString();
    Serial.println(response);
  } else {
    Serial.print("Error on HTTP request: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  }

  http.end();
}
```